# Adding some custom session variables to a JavaScript object

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have a custom session handler class which simply builds on php's session functionality (and ties in some mySQL tables).

I have a wide variety of session variables that best suits my application (primarily kept on the server side). Although I am also using jQuery to improve the usability of the front-end, and I was wondering if feeding some of the session variables (some basics and some browse preference id's) to a JS object would be a bad way to go.

Currently if I need to access any of this information at the front-end I do a ajax request to a php page specifically written to provide the appropriate response, although I am unsure if this is the best practice (actually I'm pretty sure this just creates a excess number of Ajax requests).

Has anyone got any comments on this? Would this be the best way to have this sort of information available to the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really guess it depends on many factors. I'm always having "premature optimization ..." in the back of my head.

In earlier years I rushed every little idea that came to my mind into the app. That often lead to "i made it cool but I didn't took time to fully grasp the problem I'm trying to solve; was there a problem anyway?"

Nowadays I use the obvious approach (like yours) which is fast (without scarifying performance completely on the first try) and then analyze if I'm getting into problems or not.

In other words:

1. How often do you need to access this information from different kind of loaded pages (because if you load the information once without the user reloading there's probably not much point in re-fetching it anyway) multiplied by number of concurrent clients?
2. If you write the information into a client side cookie for fast JS access, can harm be done to your application if abused (modified without application consent)? Replace "JS" and "cookie" without any kind of offline storage like WHATWG proposes it, if #1 applies.

The "fast" approach suits me, because often there's not the big investment into prior-development research. If you've done that carefully ... but then you would probably know that answer already ;)

As 3. you could always push the HTML to your client already including the data you need in JS, maybe that can work in your case. Will be interesting to see what other suggestions will come!

As I side note: I've had PHP sessions stored in DB too, until I moved them over to memcached (alert: it's a cache and not a persistent store so may be not a good idea for you case, I can live with it, I just make sure it's always running) to realize a average drop of 20% of database queries and and through this a 90% drop of write queries. And I wasn't even using any fancy Ajax yet, just the number of concurrent users.

Comment: Thanks very helpful, I had placed some thought into the prior development, but as the application is mainly for my use, I got caught up in evolution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that's definately an overkill of AJAX, are these sessions private or important not to show to a visitor? Just to throw it out there; a cookie is the easiest when it comes to both, to have the data in a javascript object makes it just as easily readable to a visitor, and when it comes down to cookies being enabled or not, without cookies you wouldn't have sessions anyway.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html is a good source about cookie handling in JS and includes two functions for reading and writing cookies.

Comment: The sessions secure an admin area for editing the sites data, The information itself is not overly sensitive to the user it relates to. 75% would be user data, 25% system indexes and alike.

Thank you for your info :)

Comment: If you don't want users to see the data then setting a javascript var and cookie is equal. Hope you find an elegant soloution.